# Получаю ошибку неподдерживаемого типа при операции получения целой части от деления

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 4 функции, которые подсчитывают количество лет/дней/часов/минут, в зависимости от введённого значения секунд.

```
def how_mc_m_in_seconds(seconds):
    """The function returns value of 
    minutes in inputed seconds"""
    if seconds // SEC_IN_MINUTE > 0:
        minutes = seconds // SEC_IN_MINUTE
        seconds = seconds - (minutes * SEC_IN_MINUTE)
        return seconds, minutes
    return seconds
```

Имею константы SEC_IN_MINUTE/HOUR/DAY/YEAR , никаких манипуляций не произвожу над ними, но в Ерор логе получаю уведомление о том, что кортеж - не поддерживает операцию //, при том, что это не кортеж, а целое число.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все функции идентичны представленной, за исключением замены констант и счётчиков

```
format_duration(3600)
```

Может ошибка в вызове функции?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда заливать код, чтобы вы могли его прочесть полностью? Я новичок в форумах и не знаю, как сделать максимально удобный для вас вопрос.

Comment: Код нужно вставить прямо в вопрос, потом выделить и нажать кнопку `{}` над редактором (или сочетание клавиш `Ctrl-K`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пишите, что у вас есть 4 функции.
Предполагаю, что вы передаете результат одной функции на вход другой.

```
SEC_IN_MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, YEAR = (60.0, 3600.0, 86400.0, 3136000.0)

def how_mc_m_in_seconds(seconds):
    """The function returns value of
    minutes in inputed seconds"""
    if seconds // SEC_IN_MINUTE > 0:
        minutes = seconds // SEC_IN_MINUTE
        seconds = seconds - (minutes * SEC_IN_MINUTE)
        return seconds, minutes
    return seconds

rezult = how_mc_m_in_seconds(3600)
print(rezult)
(0.0, 60.0)
```

**Если этот результат подать на вход еще раз - мы получим то о чем вы пишите.**

```
how_mc_m_in_seconds(rezult)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#171>", line 1, in <module>
    how_mc_m_in_seconds(rezult)
  File "<pyshell#166>", line 4, in how_mc_m_in_seconds
    if seconds // SEC_IN_MINUTE > 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: Понял суть ошибки, каким образом мне лучше вернуть minutes, если это локальная для данной функции переменная ?

Comment: Решил убрать декомпозицию функции, и сделать простую линейную функцию. Убрав функции решил проблему с аутпутом, ваш ответ помог.

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov Так нажмите галочку.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно вы передаете в качестве аргумента `seconds` функции `how_mc_m_in_seconds()` кортеж (tuple). Это легко проверить добавив отладочную информацию:

```
def how_mc_m_in_seconds(seconds):
    print(type(seconds))
    ...
```

Но вашу функцию можно заменить на более элегантный [divmod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
mins, secs = divmod(seconds, 60)
```

**NOTE:** разумеется `seconds` - должен быть типа `int` или `float`.

Примеры:

```
In [6]: mins, secs = divmod(131, 60)

In [7]: print(mins, secs)
2 11

In [8]: divmod(49, 60)
Out[8]: (0, 49)

In [9]: divmod(299, 60)
Out[9]: (4, 59)
```

Comment: Но я ведь передаю в функцию аргумент seconds - со значением 3600, и оно является целочисленным, не?

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov, а проверить (`print(type(seconds))`), не? ;)

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но в атпуте выдало class <int>, haha

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov, и ту же самую ошибку?? "Не верю!" (с) Станиславский. Можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый кусок кода?

Comment: Продолжим завтра? У меня глаза слипаются.